# Trouble understanding bitwise AND of number sequence, code provided

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

If you are given two integers A and B, where 0 <= A <=B <= 2^32. Find the bitwise AND of the integers in the range (A,B) inclusive. For example, A=12 and B=15,

12 & 13 & 14 & 15 = 12

My TA didn't do much to explain how to approach the problem and instead left everyone with a solution when office hours ended, now, I can't get the solution out of my head, but I also don't understand the solution. In the code below I've noted lines I understand and don't understand.

I have tried the pen and paper method of doing my own examples with small As and Bs, while I can visualize the code working, I am not able to grasp the theory behind why the code works.

```
private void run() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        long a = in.nextLong();
        long b = in.nextLong();
        long diff = Math.max(((long) (Math.log(b - a) / Math.log(2)) - 1), 0);
        //what does diff represent?

        long shiftA = a >> diff;    //right shift by diff okay
        long shiftB = b >> diff;    // " "
        long result = shiftA;
        for (long j = shiftA; j <= shiftB; j++) {
            result = result & j;    //don't understand the loop
        }
        result = result << diff;    //left shift, but why?
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `diff` part is just an optimization, making the code more complicated and tricky (and possibly wrong in some edge cases) to save some run time. (In general, that's a good idea only when the performance matters a lot and only with good tests. Here, we could easily spend more time understanding that optimization and getting it right than you'd save running the unoptimized program a few times.)

Let's first discuss the essential loop, setting `diff = 0`. So `a >> diff` == `a` and `result << diff` == `result`, so we can ignore all that.

The main loop implements the solution directly:

```
long result = a;
for (long j = a; j <= b; j++) {
    result = result & j;
}
```

That is, bitand (`&`) each of the values together from the range [a .. b]. Given a = 12 and b = 15, that's `12 & 13 & 14 & 15`. (Actually, if you simulate it by hand carefully, you'll notice that it computes `12 & 12 & 13 & 14 & 15`, which gets the same result.) This is an important part to understand, basic looping and bitwise math.

The `diff` part makes the code faster by dropping out the low order bits. E.g. if some input values compute `diff == 4`, then `a >> 4` shifts out the low order 4 bits of `a`, essentially `a / 16` since 2<sup>4</sup> == 16. The loop will then run 1/16th as many times. The code then shifts the result back up, `result << 4`, shifting in 0 bits, essentially `a * 16`.

On the value of `diff`, note that `Math.log(b - a) / Math.log(2)` == log<sub>2</sub>(b - a), which is the number of bits in `b - a`. It's working to compute the number of low-order bits that are going to end up zero so it can shift them out, loop many fewer times, then shift in zeros at the end.

Answer (score 3):

> what does diff represent?

`diff` uses [change of base formula for logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) to compute the number of bits in representation of the difference `b-a`. If the difference takes `K` bits to represent, then the last `K-1` bits of the result of one of the numbers from the `[a..b]` range will all be set to zero, meaning that you can clear them out in the result. Hence the left shift by `diff` at the end: it shifts `diff` zeros into the result.

> I don't understand the loop

The loop goes through bit representations reduced 2<sup>diff</sup> times, i.e. uses only the upper bits of `a` and `b`. Since the lower `diff` bits will be set to zero anyway, this solution counts by 2<sup>diff</sup> instead of counting by `1`, reducing the time it takes to arrive at the result.

Consider an example of `a=23` and `b=39`. `diff` is equal to `3`. Here are the representations, with comma separating out the last 3 bits:

```
d       b
-- -------
23 010,111
24 011,000
25 011,001
26 011,010
27 011,011
28 011,100
29 011,101
30 011,110
31 011,111
32 100,000 <<-- The last diff bits will be set to zero somewhere in the range
33 100,001
34 100,010
35 100,011
36 100,100
37 100,101
38 100,110
39 100,111
```

Since the last three bits are guaranteed to reach all zeros, the loop can count by eight, instead of counting by one. This reduces the execution speed eight-fold. Counting by eight is done by shifting the number right by `diff` first, then counting by one, and then shifting left by `diff`.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks for the correction! I updated the example to go to 39, so that the log would be 4 and `diff` would be 3.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler, and also easier to understand:

```
 long result = firstValue;
 for ( long i=result+1; i <= lastValue; i++ ) {
   result &= i;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the straightforward solution is a lot slower when `lastValue` is a lot higher than `firstValue`.